# Printing multi-character tokens in YACC error messages

Tags: bison, yacc

If a syntax error is detected by Yacc and verbose errors is defined, an error message is printed, for example

```
unexpected '[', expecting BECOMES
```

Is there a way to replace the token name for multi-character tokens (e.g. `BECOMES`) with the actual string (e.g. `:=`) in the error message? The reason I'm asking is that it may not be obvious to the user of the parser that `BECOMES` stand for `:=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a human-readable version of a token name by adding it in quotes after the token name in the `%token` definition:

```
%token BECOMES "':='"
```

This will change the error message to:

```
unexpected '[', expecting ':='
```

Comment: Thanks! For some strange reason the single quotes *and* the double quotes are printed in the error message (`expecting "':='"`). If I remove the single quotes no quotes are printed (`expecting :=`). I use Bison 3.3.2.